# Добавление библиотек с нестандартным расширением *.so.6 в проект AndrodiStudio

Tags: android, библиотеки

Существует библиотека **foo.so**, собранная для использования в ***Android*** приложении. Данная библиотека имеет зависимости от библиотек с расширениями, созданными с учетом правил Linux с указанием версий в суффиксе расширения. Например, **librt.so.1**. Проблема в том, что данные библиотеки с таким именем на конце не удается упаковать в apk, т.к. расширение, использующее на конце версию типа ***.so.1** или ***.so.6**, при сборке игнорируются. Как результат, либо зависимости вообще не попадают в apk, либо попадают обернутые **lib**name.**so**. Например, ***libfoo.so.1.so***. Есть ли у кого идеи на эту тему?

Answer (score 0):

Народ предлагает следующий workaround:

1)Пихаем все `*.so.X` в `assets`

2)В рантайме вытаскиваем либу из `assets` сохраняем ее во внутреннее хранилище приложения

3)Загружаем сохраненную нативную либу из внутреннего хранилища

```
AssetManager am = applicationContext.getAssets(); 
in = am.open(SO_LIB_NAME);
File privateStorageDir = applicationContext.getFilesDir();
String libPath = privateStorageDir.getAbsolutePath();  // копируем либу сюда

System.load(libPath + "/" + SO_LIB_NAME); //загружаем либу
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434262/472270)

Comment: Добр день! Спасибо. Вероятно всего, этот вариант работает. И сейчас я пытаюсь его освоить: программно копировать из assets в internal Storage. Пока имею проблему, связанную с тем что линкер пытается найти любу ***.s0.X** еще до старта 'onCreate()’… Думаю, что нужно собрать отдельно от основного проекта *.so и потом его подключить… Но, важным для меня остается следующее. Ответ, на основе которого, мы здесь общаемся был оставлен в оригинале более _8 лет назад.._.  Неужели в официальной документации Android developers не появилось темы для подобной ситуации?

Comment: В моем случае это не сработало. В частности, при попытке подключить любу libc.so.6 выдается ошибка: _dlopen failed: cannot find verneed/verdef for version index=32770 referenced by symbol "_res" at "/data/data/com.example.testbltestserandposbin/files/libc.so.6"_ Бороться с которой вообще никак не понятно...

Comment: это выкидывает `loadLibrary()`? 1) Вы же помните, что в `loadLibrary()` именование либы должно быть другое... 2) точно уверены, что файл `/data/data/com.example.testbltestserandposbin/files/libc.so.6` существует и корректно сохранен? Проверьте с помощью `adb`

Comment: 1) Это выкидывает 'System.load()', где, как я понял, указывается абсолютный путь... 2) Существует. Проверял 'new File(...).exists'. Проверка с помощью adb может дать др результат?

Comment: "Вы же помните, что в loadLibrary() именование либы должно быть другое..." - да. Если правильно помню, например, libnXXX.so - в loadLibrary('XXX')... Но, в контексте обсуждения файлов типа libXXX.so.6 - я что-то упустил? Можно тоже loadLibrary('XXX')?